# Simple service injection in ASP.Net Core does not call constructor

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I need to define a new self-created service inside the "ConfigureServices" method inside the "Startup" class.
And I also need some parameters to the new service, like so:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAppEnvironment>(sp => new AppEnvironment("a", "b", "c", true, false, false));
```

But the constructor inside my App Environment class never gets called :-( (I get now action and / or output from the method... The AppEnvironment excerpt here:

```
    public class AppEnvironment : IAppEnvironment
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Singleton constructor (the singleton instance is managed by the .net core env)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="envSection"></param>
        public AppEnvironment(
            string dbcon_local,
            string dbcon_test,
            string dbcon_release,
            bool islocal,
            bool istest,
            bool isrelease)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("########### this is never happening");
        }
...
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: The constructor will call when you will use `AppEnvironment` but not when you add it to DI container `services.AddSingleton<IAppEnvironment>(...`. Add `AppEnvironment ` as a parameter of constructor of a controller then call any action of contoller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The singleton will only be created when it is injected into something.  If for some reason you want to force it to be created in your startup, you can do something like this instead.

```
var appEnv = new AppEnvironment("a", "b", "c", true, false, false));
services.AddSingleton<IAppEnvironment>(appEnv);
```

Edit:
To further explain, when you use `=>` you are really just passing a delegate to a function, but that function has not been executed at that time.  You are passing it to services so that it can be called when needed at a later time.

Comment: Thanks for your help....

I injected the class into my DbContext class... I tried to consume it inside the OnConfiguring method... But no result... Still the constructor doesn't get called :(

Comment: I finally got it... I got some type conversion wrong.... your hint was right!!!!

Comment: If your Service itself is using Dependency Injection and you can't declare it before adding as a singleton, you can call `app.Services.GetService<MyService>();`  after running `var app = builder.Build();` to instantiate it.